# PSQL timeline conflict prevent start of master

Tags: postgresql

We had an outage on one of our PSQL 14 (managed by Zalando) due to k8s control plane being unreachable for 30min.
Control plane is now ok but master PSQL does not want to start:

```
LOG,00000,"listening on IPv4 address ""0.0.0.0"", port 5432"
LOG,00000,"listening on IPv6 address ""::"", port 5432"
LOG,00000,"listening on Unix socket ""/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"""
LOG,00000,"database system was shut down at 2023-01-30 02:51:10 UTC"
WARNING,01000,"specified neither primary_conninfo nor restore_command",,"The database server will regularly poll the pg_wal subdirectory to check for files placed there."
LOG,00000,"entering standby mode"
FATAL,XX000,"requested timeline 5 is not a child of this server's history","Latest checkpoint is at 2/82000028 on timeline 4, but in the history of the requested timeline, the server forked off from that timeline at 0/530000A0."
LOG,00000,"startup process (PID 23007) exited with exit code 1"
LOG,00000,"aborting startup due to startup process failure"
LOG,00000,"database system is shut down"
```

We can see in archive_status folder:

```
-rw-------. 1 postgres postgres 0 Jan 30 02:51 000000040000000200000081.ready
-rw-------. 1 postgres postgres 0 Jan 30 02:51 00000005.history.done
```

Would you know how we can recover safely from this?
I guess switching back to timeline 4 would be enough as timeline 5 was made after start of outage.

Comment: That doesn't sound like the master having a problem, but like the standby requesting something it shouldn't. You'll have to provide more relevant log entries.

Comment: We use a k8s STS and as the master does not start properly we do not have any standby node running

Comment: Well, then explain to me who it is that requested timeline 5. Please show more of the log.

Comment: I believed it was the master itself which want to start with timeline 5: https://pastebin.com/0sBdHPmt
We do not see other members with patronictl list:
+ Cluster: XXX-postgresql (7188078315812995153) ----------+----+-----------+
| Member            | Host        | Role    | State        | TL | Lag in MB |
+-------------------+-------------+---------+--------------+----+-----------+
| XXX-postgresql-0 | 10.170.3.88 | Replica | start failed |    |   unknown |
+-------------------+-------------+---------+--------------+----+-----------+
We do have WAL S3 replication, could it be related?

Comment: The logs I provided with pastebin link are the ones within pg_log directory. There is not more than this there, it's only looping what I pasted.
Which other logs would you need and how could I provide to you efficiently?

Comment: Ah, ok, I didn't see the link. You should always add relevant information to the question.

Answer (score 0):

The server is started in standby mode. Remove `standby.signal` if you want to start the server as primary server.

Comment: `standby.signal` is automatically recreated after few secs and pod keep being started as replica.
I also tried to promote manually using `pg_ctl promote` but sadly it did not work:
```postgres@xs2a-postgresql-0:~$ pg_ctl promote  --pgdata=/home/postgres/pgdata/pgroot/data
pg_ctl: PID file "/home/postgres/pgdata/pgroot/data/postmaster.pid" does not exist
Is server running?```

Comment: You have to tell your Kubernetes that it should start this instance as master.